# How do I combine the text value of multiple (same name) nodes and update another node if the combined length > 20 characters?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to combine all Node2 values into a single Node2. However, if the combined string is greater than 20 characters, I want to append the combined string to Node1 and truncate Node2 to only 20 characters.

```
<Parent>
    <Node1>Some Text</Node1>
    <Node2>Some Name1</Node2>
    <Node2>Some Name2</Node2>
    <Node2>Some Name3</Node2>
    <Node2>Some Name4</Node2>
    <Node2>Some Name5</Node2>
</Parent>
```

The desired result is:

```
<Parent> 
  <Node1>Some Text; Node2: Some Name1, Some Name2, Some Name3, Some Name4, Some Name5</Node1> 
  <Node2>Some Name1, Some Nam</Node2> 
</Parent>
```

Comment: What is the expected result if the length is not greater than 20 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following XSLT-2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:template match="/Parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:variable name="n2">
            <xsl:value-of select="Node2" separator=", "/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Node1><xsl:value-of select="Node1, if (string-length($n2) > 20) then concat('; Node2: ',$n2) else ''" separator=""/></Node1>
        <Node2><xsl:value-of select="substring($n2,1,20)" /></Node2>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent>
   <Node1>Some Text; Node2: Some Name1, Some Name2, Some Name3, Some Name4, Some Name5</Node1>
   <Node2>Some Name1, Some Nam</Node2>
</Parent>
```

Comment: @Tony: Glad I could help. It would be common to accept this answer - thank you, too.